# How can we prove that $\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\lfloor 2^nX\rfloor\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\uparrow X$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space
- $X$ be $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable

Moreover, let $$X_n:=\frac{1}{2^n}\lfloor 2^nX\rfloor$$ How can we prove that $\left(X_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically increasing and converges to $X$?

I'm failing to show that $X_n\le X_{n+1}$.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem? Although this is a math site, we look for questions that include more background than just a problem statement, and also for questions that show what the asker is thinking, not just a statement of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove monotonicity, observe that if $2^nX=k+d$ where $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $0\le d <1$ then you have that $$\begin{align*}\lfloor 2^{n+1}X \rfloor&=\lfloor 2\cdot2^nX \rfloor=\lfloor 2\cdot (k+d) \rfloor=\lfloor 2k+2d \rfloor\\&=2k \text{ or } 2k+1\\& \ge 2k\\&= 2\lfloor (k+d)\rfloor\\&=2\lfloor 2^nX\rfloor\end{align*}$$ This implies that $$\begin{align*}\lfloor 2^{n+1}X \rfloor \ge 2 \lfloor 2^nX \rfloor &\iff \frac{1}{2^n}\lfloor 2^{n+1}X \rfloor \ge \frac{1}{2^n}2 \lfloor 2^nX \rfloor \\&\iff \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\lfloor 2^{n+1}X \rfloor \ge \frac{1}{2^n} \lfloor 2^nX \rfloor \\&\iff X_{n+1}\ge X_n\end{align*}$$

Comment: I think that was the "tricky" part. Since $Y_n\le Y$ and $$Y_n\ge\frac{1}{2^n}\left(2^nY-1\right)=Y-\frac{1}{2^n}\to Y$$ we should have $Y_n\to Y$ by the squeeze theorem, right?

Comment: Yes, this looks correct!